# Error occurred on restoring nuget package in visual studio "The path is not of a legal form"

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, dotnet-sdk

Facing issue while restoring the nuget packages in visual studio and getting the following error, 'The path is not of a legal form'. Below are the configuration details.

Visual Studio 2019 - v16.5.4
Nuget Package Manager - 5.5.0
dotnet SDK - 3.1.201

Answer (score 0):

I noticed I got the same error when Visual studio thought I didn't install all the nuget packages that was referenced in my packages.json. Once I clicked on the prompt to install the missing packages then the usual console commands worked without getting that error

To resolve try to Right click on your solution in Visual Studio 2019 and select Restore nuget packages. Then run the console command again